# Work Sheet Change

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to put together a macro that will put in a time stamp.

I have 2 sheets `input` and `dashboard`

When cell A2 on `input` changes I want a the function NOW to be used on cell M8 on `dashboard`

I pressed alt + F11 on the `input` sheet to bring up the vba editor and used:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$A$2" Then

        Sheets("Dashboard").Select
        Range("M8").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=NOW()"
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End If

End Sub
```

It fails at the line:

```
Range("M8").Select
```

what is wrong with the code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because in the worksheet code if you do not specify the parent to the range it assumes the sheet in which the code resides not the active sheet like a module.  So `input` no longer being active you cannot select the cell in that sheet.

You can replace everything in your IF with this one line:

```
Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("M8").Value2 = Now()
```

It will paste the current date/time as a value not a formula and without the need to select or activate anything.